# dynamic javascript load and subscribe to event based on data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, hook, pubnub

I have a javascript client using [pubnub](/questions/tagged/pubnub) for messaging.  I'm subscribing to a channel like so:

```js
    pubnub.subscribe({
        channel : chnl,
        message : function(m){
            var msg = $.parseJSON(m);
            processMessage(msg);
        }
    );
```

I have a bunch of widgets/components that currently only consist of HTML which are dynamically loaded.  Right now, `processMessage()` basically just said "If the message ID is widget1 then do a bunch of stuff".  I would like to modify the component files to include javascript that handles all the widget data, and some how register a hook to detect when a PubNub message comes in with an ID that matches the widget.

How can I do this?

*See [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330624/routing-and-parsing-json-messages-to-different-javascript-widgets) on programmers.stackexchange.com for more info.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a simple callback map and do a lookup when a message comes in.

Something like:

```
var callbackMap = {};

function registerCallback(id, callback) {
  callbackMap[id] = callback;
}

function processMessage(msg) {
  callbackMap[msg.id](msg.data);
}
```

In each component, you would register:

```
registerCallback('widget1', function(data) {
  //do something for widget1 with data
});
```

And on message:

```
pubnub.subscribe({
  channel: chnl,
  message: function(m){
    var msg = $.parseJSON(m);
    processMessage(msg);
  }
);
```

Comment: Couldn't I just skip the `processMessage()` function and call `callbackMap[msg]()` directly from the pubnub listener?

Comment: And acutally, `msg` contains the entire payload.  How would I register the callback with the ID (`msg.id`) and still have access to the entire data (`msg.data`)?

Comment: Sure. If it was me, I would just expose the processMessage function and keep the map internal, but it makes no difference.

Comment: I'm fine with "keeping the map internal" but is there a benefit or is it just personal preference?

Comment: Personal preference, it's functionally the same. See my edit for dealing with the data.

Comment: Looks great, I'll give  it a go and report back. Thanks